# Table with inset cell, to convey two levels of information

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am attempting to create a table in LaTeX, where each cell is divided in two. The purpose of the table is to communicate two pieces of information. However, it is a 10 X 10 table. This means it will not be pleasant to read the table. So, I thought to better present the information, I could have one piece of information in the inset cell (e.g. TD) and the other in the grey filled cell. For example, like this table:

[image: Table with inset cell]

How can I do this?

Comment: From tags I suspect that you like to draw table with TikZ, an I correct? In this case each table cell is consisting with main node (with gray fill) which ha on upper left corner small white node with TD? Please clarify your question and show us what you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally got it working!!! This is what I used.

```
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\insetcell}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (node1) [rectangle, draw = white, rounded corners, align = right, text depth = 0.1cm, text height = 1cm , text width = 1.5cm] at (0,0) {#1};
\node [anchor = north west, text depth = 0.05cm, text height = 0.5cm , text width = 0.5cm] at (node1.north west) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes, nodes = {draw, rounded corners, text centered}, column sep = 0.5 cm, row sep = 0.5 cm]
{
\insetcell{1}{3} & \insetcell{1}{3} & \\
\insetcell{1}{3} &   & \\
\insetcell{1}{3} & \insetcell{I hope this works}{3} & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Final table]